Primeng Remove vertical line from Vertical Stepper
Currently i am using primeng stepper vertical. In that i need to remove vertical line for all steps. Can you help that. Please find screen shot for same.This is primeng vertical stepper image.
Is there anything like ::ng-deep we can use to remove this vertical line?

I think something like this ::ng-deep [class*=lineCssClass]

I found below solution after searching.
 ::ng-deep .p-stepper-separator {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 2px;
    height: auto;
    margin-inline-start: 0 !important;
} 

I hope it will help.
